# Add wifi ssid and password to keychain for ios on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, keychain, ssid

Is it possible to save the ssid and password for a known wifi network programatically to the iPhone?

I don't have any clues beyond: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html

Can someone point me to a github project that perhaps handles this usecase as a utility ... or perhaps reference some more code?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this because iOS keychain is isolated for each app. But it may be possible on a jailbroken device. (See http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dataprotection/wiki/KeychainViewer)

The Captive Network has nothing to do with the ssid and password.

Comment: Even if its isolated for each app, can i make the ssid + password known to the iPhone for at least the app in context? I thought captive network might help because it *might* let my app register the wifi SSID that the app knows about with Captive Network Support, and then allow the app to assume responsibility for authenticating with that wifi ssid ... no?